# Is It Possible To Add A Custom App To The IOS Control Center?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

If one writes a custom app is it possible to be able to add a shortcut to the `iOS` lock screen? Or **is that reserved for Apple sanctioned apps?**

Currently, one can go into settings and add, say, the voice memo app to the lock screen control center. Of course, these shortcuts are available when you've signed in as well (by getting to the control center).

I like to use React Native and Expo, but my question is more general than that (but let me know if you know of any Expo tricks for this).

Comment: No, this is not a supported extension for non-Apple apps